# Where select expert button in windows form crystal report viewer?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I used crystal report viewer expert button in my old project in vb.

[Crystal report viewer old in VB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhrwv.png)
or [Crystal report viewer old in VB](http://uupload.ir/files/75iq_vb.jpg)

But i can't find it crystal report viewer version 13.
What is the reason that i can't find it?

[Crystal report viewer old in VS 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAj9i.jpg)
or [Crystal report viewer old in VS 2015](http://uupload.ir/files/8rkt_c_cr13.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option was removed as Crystal transitioned from the RDC (COM) object model to the .NET object model.

Comment: Do you have a solution for filtering the report view?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to use parameters.
More complex solution is to use the Crystal runtime to manipulate record selection logic.
Or export the report data to a format (Excel, JS Grid, JS Pivot Table...) that provides filtering options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why did they remove this option from the software? Usually in softwares increases the possibilities, not less.

Comment: They dropped that feature as they switched object model architectures (COM --> .NET).
Probably a mix of limited development resources and low use of that feature by the user community.

Comment: In our company, many of our software are programmed in VB 6. And all users use this feature in reports. And we are now converting applications to .Net when we have this problem.